# Passing double variable to a function with long parameter

Tags: java, math, double, overflow, long-integer

I have a constructor with double parameter, which need to preserve 6 decimal number. To convert the number into (numerator, denominator) format, it passes the number into another function which accepts long parameters.

```
// A double value (6 decimal will be used)
public DoubleToLong(double d)
{
    System.out.println("Double is " + d);          //  Double is 9.2233720368547E13
    convert((long) (d * 1000000), 1000000);
}

public void convert(long num, long den)
{

    System.out.println("Numerator: " + num + " Denominator: " + den);  // Numerator: 9223372036854775807 Denominator: 1000000
}
```

When 9223372036854L passed to constructor, 
Numerator: 9223372036853999616 Denominator: 1000000 -> (OK)

When 92233720368547L passed to constructor,
Numerator: 9223372036854775807 Denominator: 1000000 -> (NOK)

Overflow occurs on multiplication with 1000000. How to modify the constructor to use all long values as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about what you're asking - but yes, if you try to go outside the bounds of `long`, it *will* overflow. (`Long.MAX_VALUE` is 9223372036854775807, the second value you're seeing.) Perhaps you need to use `BigInteger` and `BigDecimal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the max size of a long. To avoid the problem you need to use a [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

But you will need to also rewrite the convert function to be able to use BigDecimal.

Comment: Yes, exactly the issue is when (d * 1000000) go outside the bounds of long. But the "convert" function is actually inside another class which accepts (long, long) only. Unable to find any other alternative to use bigger long values. So should I say that there will be a limitation through this constructor on using values above (Long.Max_VALUE / 100000) ?

Comment: If the convert function is outside of your scope, you have to accept its signature. The long is the definition domain of the function, so there is no mistake in saying you have limitations here.